# watch parent controller value from ui router state resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my AngularJS app using `ui-router` I have three states. The parent state in the controller resolves a promise and on a successful request, executes the code.

In the child state `portfolio.modal.patent`, using `$stateProvider` and the `resolve` method, I make another request. The issue is that I need to make the `resolve` method wait until the promise is returned in the parent controller `portfolio`.

**States**

```
$stateProvider
.state('portfolio', {
    url: '/portfolio',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/portfolio/portfolio.tpl.htm',
    controller: 'portfolioCtrl',
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
})
.state('portfolio.modal', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        "modal": {
            templateUrl: "app/templates/patent/modal.html"
        }
    }
})
.state('portfolio.modal.patent', {
    url: '/:patentId',
    resolve: { //NEED TO MAKE THIS RESOLVE AFTER PORTFOLIO CONTROLLER HAS RETURNED ITS PROMISE
        patent: ['$stateParams', 'patentsRestService', function($stateParams, patentsRestService) {
            return patentsRestService.fetchPatentItem($stateParams.patentId);

        }],
    }
}
```

**Portfolio controller**

```
function portfolioCtrl() {
    $scope.promise
    .then(function(response) {
          //WHEN PROMISIS RETURNED, THEN RESOLVE DATA IN PORTFOLIO.MODAL.PATENT
    })
}
```

**Question**

How do I resolve the child state `portfolio.modal.patent` data after the promise has been returned from the parent state controller `portfolioCtrl`

Comment: Why don't you use resolve in parent state also?

Comment: Performance issues. It has to fetch a lot of data and the state doesn't load until it's been resolved, impacting UX

Comment: As a possible workaround, try to store $q promise in your service and resolve it when parent successfully fetched data

Comment: @withrp that's the idea but how would I go about checking that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fast possible workaround how you can try to solve your problem using service as a bridge between requests

Example:

```
// service
const bridge = $q.defer();
const resolveBridgePromise = data => bridge.resolve(data);
const getBridgePromise = () => bridge.promise;

const fetchDataInParentCtrl = () => {
    $timeout(() => {
        console.log('data fetched in parent');

        resolveBridgePromise({ key: 'fetched data' });
    }, 2000);
  };

// controller
fetchDataInParentCtrl();

// resolver
getBridgePromise()
  .then(data => {
      console.log('Do http request here for your child data: ', data);
  });
```